# EF Code First: Foreign Key With Where Clause?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

Given entities like these:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EntityTwo> EntityTwos { get; set; }
}

public class EntityTwo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

Normally, `Entity.EntityTwos` would return all EntityTwo entities where `EntityId` equals `Entity.Id`. Is it possible to rig up the model so that property returns entities that join on that Id, but also have `EntityTwo.TypeId == 2` (essentially adding a where clause to the join)?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do a manual join rather than relying on the navigational properties to create an implied join.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve this by thinking about it a different way.  Your join keys would be:

```
{ TypeId, Id } equals { 2, Id }
```

Maybe it's possible to use a constant as one of the two composite keys?  See Ladislav's  [composite key as foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436731/composite-key-as-foreign-key) answer.

Comment: Seemed promising, but the composite mapping requires two *properties* (adding a property on the entity with a constant value didn't work either). This similar question/answer seems to confirm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526497/literal-or-constant-as-part-of-composite-key-in-ef-code-first